# Using JavaScript bring up the list by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

Use the 'for' sentence, I want to bring up the list by clicking the button.

Only the pressed button works, the rest is none.

doesn't solve it well.

```
<body>
<div>
<ul>
<li><button class="test_button"> button1 </button></li>
<li><button class="test_button"> button2 </button></li>
<li><button class="test_button"> button3 </button></li>
<li><button class="test_button"> button4 </button></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<ol>
<li class="test_list">list1<li>
<li class="test_list">list2<li>
<li class="test_list">list3<li>
<li class="test_list">list3<li>
</ol>
<div>
</body>
    <script>
   let i;
   let btn = document.getElementsByClassName(page_faq_tab_button);
   let agl = document.getElementsByClassName(accordion_group_list);

   btn.addEventListener("click", btnFunction);

   function btnFunction() {
       for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
           btn[i].style.color = "#AAAA";
           agl[i].style.display = "block";
       }
   }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Is it that you want to display the lists one by one using a for loop on button click?

Comment: yes just 1 list

Comment: Do you need to use a for-loop? There are easier ways...

Comment: Try do tidy the code and present a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showList() {
   var myArray = jQuery.makeArray($('.test_button'));
   for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      myArray[i].style.display = "block";
   }
}
// The following is just to hide your buttons first:
$(function() {
  $('.test_button').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul>
<li><button class="test_button"> button1 </button></li>
<li><button class="test_button"> button2 </button></li>
<li><button class="test_button"> button3 </button></li>
<li><button class="test_button"> button4 </button></li>
</ul>
</div>

<button onclick="showList()">Show list</button>
```

Please note, though, there are much better ways to do this:

## Using forEach

```js
function showList() {
   var myArray = jQuery.makeArray($('.test_button'));
   myArray.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
      arr[index].style.display = "block";
   });
}
```

## The easiest way

```js
function showList() {
   $('.test_button').show();
}
```